# How do I assign values to keys when I merge 2 objects with .map()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using `.map()` to cycle through an object and places some values in to a 2nd object.

I am doing this as such:

```
function convertGraphItems(name, data) {
  return ({ name, data, type: 'bar', stack: true });
}

var generatedArr = [...dataByAccountName.entries()].map(convertGraphItems);
```

However, I seem to be unable to assign 'name' and 'data' to their respective keys.

I have tried `return ({ name: name, data: data, type: 'bar', stack: true });` but this does not achieve what I want.

My **desired** result should look like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Savings",
        "data": [
            5474.18,
            114031.26,
            127890.72
        ],
        "type": "bar",
        "stack": true
    }
]
```

But my **current** result is:

```
[
    {
        "name": [
            "Savings",
            [
                5474.18,
                114031.26,
                127890.72
            ]
        ],
        "data": 0,
        "type": "bar",
        "stack": true
    }
]
```

Would anyone know how I could assign `data` and `name` to their respective keys?

EDIT: source array looks like:

```
[
    {
        "key": "Savings",
        "value": [
            5474.18,
            114031.26,
            127890.72
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: How does your source array look like?

Comment: @decpk added above

Comment: Where does `dataByAccountName` come from? Since you're using `.entries()`, I assumed it was a `Map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `convertGraphItems` function into `map` and you are expecting `name` as `key` and `data` as `value`, but this is not the case here.

In `map` the first argument is the value and second is the `index`.
You have to make `convertGraphItems` compatible so you can pass value externally as:

```
[...dataByAccountName.entries()].map(function ([_, { key, value }]) {
  return convertGraphItems(key, value);
});
```

```js
const dataByAccountName = [
  {
    key: "Savings",
    value: [5474.18, 114031.26, 127890.72],
  },
];

function convertGraphItems(name, data) {
  return { name, data, type: "bar", stack: true };
}

var generatedArr = [...dataByAccountName.entries()].map(function ([, v]) {
  const { key, value } = v;
  return convertGraphItems(key, value);
});
console.log(generatedArr);
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `Array.prototype.entries()` 

Comment: @Phil I too was thinking that why `phil` has used Map here. He could have achieved the result using map and entries also. Even though the solution with Map is great and works perfect. Because you know what I've learned a lot from your answers. 

Comment: Using array entries is a really odd choice (for the OP, not you). It doesn't look like they're interested in the indices at all. Your result also doesn't look like what OP wanted

Answer (score 1):

The first two arguments passed to the [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback are

- **`element`**

  The current element being processed in the array.
- **`index`**

  The index of the current element being processed in the array.

It seems unlikely that you'd want `data` to be the index.

```js
const dataByAccountName = [{"key":"Savings","value":[5474.18,114031.26,127890.72]}]

const generatedArr = dataByAccountName.map(({ key: name, value: data }) => ({
  name,
  data,
  type: "bar",
  stack: true
}))

console.log(generatedArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

If you're using something else that produces *entries* (like a Map), then this is how you'd map it

```js
const dataByAccountName = new Map()
dataByAccountName.set("Savings", [
  5474.18,
  114031.26,
  127890.72
])

const generatedArr = Array.from(dataByAccountName, ([ name, data ]) => ({
  name,
  data,
  type: "bar",
  stack: true
}))

console.log(generatedArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

I've used `Array.from()` since IMO it looks better than `[...map.entries()].map()` and achieves exactly the same thing.

Note that the first (and only) argument passed to the mapping callback is a destructured array as opposed to two separate args.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to do this without the arrow function? For some reason my work's compilers don't like them

Comment: @MeltingDog what _"compilers"_? Assuming your [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) works, it seems very strange that arrow functions would not

Comment: it's a bit beyond me - they use some .net CMS that must compile the .JS into one file or something like that. I'm not sure the spread operator wiill work either, to be honest but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source array already available as you included in the question, you don't need a separate function for it.

```js
const sources = [{
  "key": "Savings",
  "value": [5474.18, 114031.26, 127890.72]
}]
const parsedData = sources.map(({key, value}) => ({
  name: key,
  data: value,
  type: 'bar',
  stack: true
}));

console.log(parsedData)
```